# Asynchronous Kafka consumer in Spring Batch Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-kafka

In our Spring Batch application workers, item processors are further interacting with another service asynchronously through Kafka. The requirement here is we required an acknowledgement in order to retry failed batches and the condition is to not wait for the acknowledgement.

Is there any mechanism in spring batch by which we can asynchronously consume Kafka ?
Is it possible to rerun specific local worker step in rerun of job?
[image]

We implement producers and consumers over same step using Spring batch decider. Thus, during the first run it will only produce Kafka and on second run it will consume the Kafka.

We are looking for solution where we can asynchronously consume Kafka in Spring batch application in order to rerun specific worker step.

Comment: What is your setup? Is it a chunk-oriented step? remote chunking, remote partitioning? This is key to correctly answer your question. A remotely partitioned step can be restarted (only failed partitions will be restarted). Please share your code or more details about your setup to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine 
It is remote partitioning. Also added design image for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Nice diagram BTW! I added an answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any mechanism in spring batch by which we can asynchronously consume Kafka ? Is it possible to rerun specific local worker step in rerun of job?

According to your diagram, you are doing that call from an item processor. The closest "feature" you can get from Spring Batch is the `AsyncItemProcessor`. This is a special processor that processes items asynchronously in a separate thread. The callback is unwrapped in an `AsyncItemWriter` with the result of the call.

Other than that, I do not see any other obvious way to do that with a built-in feature from Spring Batch. So you would have to manage that in a custom `ItemProcessor`.